# Integrating MongoDB metrices with Cloud watch

Tags: mongodb, aws, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

We are hosting mongodb in AWS environment and planning to create incident in Servicenow using AWS Cloud watch alarm facility

Has anyone integrated MongoDB Monitoring metrices with Cloud watch to create Incident ?

As i am completely new to AWS, i got stuck with the integration of mongodb metrices with cloud watch

Any link/lead would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As per @AndrewAslinger blog [here](http://owaaa.github.io/cloudwatch/amazon/aws/mongodb/devops/autoscaling/2014/01/14/mongo_cloudwatch.html) The Amazon [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) is a useful tool for monitoring your compute resources, services, and applications running in AWS. Amazon automatically publishes metrics for you when you use many different AWS Services.

As aws documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_architecture.html) Amazon CloudWatch is basically a metrics repository. An AWS service—such as Amazon EC2—puts metrics into the repository, and you retrieve statistics based on those metrics. If you put your own custom metrics into the repository, you can retrieve statistics on these metrics as well.

You can configure alarm actions to stop, start, or terminate an Amazon EC2 instance when certain criteria are met. In addition, you can create alarms that initiate Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling and Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) actions on your behalf. For more information about creating CloudWatch alarms, see [Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchAlarms).

For further your ref [here](http://owaaa.github.io/cloudwatch/amazon/aws/mongodb/devops/autoscaling/2014/01/14/mongo_cloudwatch.html), [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html) and [here](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/centralized-log-management-with-aws-cloudwatch-part-1-of-3/)